# Evaluating a double intgeral over a plane region

Tags: integration

I'm trying to evaluate the following double integral:$$\iint_{D}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\,dA$$where $D$ is the disk of radius 1 with center at $(0,1)$.
Is there a useful substitution to make? If I try to use polar coordinates, then I get a tedious integral.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the other answer is that was posted a while ago, but this looks like an integral that is best suited for polar coordinates. Use $x^2+y^2 = r^2$ and $dA = r\cdot drd\theta$ to get $$\int \int_D \frac{r}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}drd\theta$$ I'd integrate with respect to $r$ first as it lends itself nicely to $u$-sub. The rest of the integral should be a breeze.